# Generate random numbers in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a table with random numbers filled in like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>315</td>
    <td>356</td>
    <td>441</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>664</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>236</td>
    <td>742</td>
  </tr>
...
<!-- more rows like the above -->
</table>
```

my Html is:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{randNumGen()}}</td>
    <td>{{randNumGen()}}</td>
    <td>{{randNumGen()}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My JS is:

```
app.controller('TableCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
  $scope.randNumGen = function() {
    return Math.floor((Math.rand()*1000)+1);
  }
});
```

It returns all the random number like how i want, however it throws a JS error saying:

> "Error: [$rootScope: infdig]"

and wont run any scripts below this controller.

Comment: it might be only in your pasted code, but you are not closing your controller function

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but no that's not the issue i have.

Comment: Plus, I assume you are using `Math.random()`?

Comment: Yeah sorry - that was a typo - I have Math.random()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `randomNumGen()` is, in angulars definition a scoped variable. If it detects a change to the result of this function it will trigger a digest. As the result is different in nearly all cases this will result in an infinite digest loop.

You would be better off building your array of random numbers before the digest loop and then assigning a static non changing array to the scope and thus not causing any undesired / unwanted digest loops occuring.

One approach would be to build a simplistic factory to generate the array for you when the controller is loaded. Then just output its contents.

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .factory('generator', function() {
        function buildRandArray(length) {
            var arr = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < (length || 10); i++) {
                var fill = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    fill.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1));
                }
                arr.push(fill);
            }

            return arr;
        }

        return {
            buildRandArray : buildRandArray
        }
    })

    .controller('TableCtrl', function($scope, generator) {
        $scope.items = generator.buildRandArray(10);
    });
```

Now your HTML would be

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td ng-repeat="number in item">
        {{number}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks David, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
  $scope.randNumGen = function() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
}
});
```

I noticed Math.rand is not a function in ur code !! use Math.random

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `Math.random()` instead of `Math.rand()`? See [reference on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)